# I can't use different function to extract data and filter out from beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get request text from website and use beautifulsoup to filter out data. But when I wrote this code its giving me an error and I can't run it please help.

I have tried to declare text as global variable but I can't understand how to use another function variable in some other function.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

global website
global text

website = raw_input('Enter Website: ')

def getconnect():
    req = requests.get(website)
    text = req.text

def bs4(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text , 'html.parser')
    print soup.title
    print soup.p

def main():
    return

getconnect()
bs4()
```

I want to extract data from the website an run the data through beautifulsoup using different functions. I have just recently started the programming.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. The way you're declaring `global` variables is incorrect. You need to use the `global` keyword *inside* functions if you want to modify the value of a global variable.
2. You've defined your `bs4` function `def bs4(text):` such that it's expecting an argument. However, you're then calling it with no argument `bs4()`.

Here's a working implementation:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = ""
website = raw_input('Enter Website: ')

def getconnect():
    global text
    req = requests.get(website)
    text = req.text

def bs4():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text , 'html.parser')
    print soup.title
    print soup.p

getconnect()
bs4()
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55470747

However, it's a better practice to avoid using global variables when possible:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getconnect(website):
    req = requests.get(website)
    return req.text

def bs4(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text , 'html.parser')
    print soup.title
    print soup.p

text = getconnect(raw_input('Enter Website: '))
bs4(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse():
    website = input('Enter Website: ')
    text = requests.get(website).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title)
    print(soup.p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse()
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass the text to the `bs4` method.

you should have this:

```
text = getconnect()
bs4(text)
```